# How to exclude an object from KInematic Trajectory Optimization #Drake

Tags: drake

I want to enable a gripper to do pick&place an object from a shelf. For this, I am trying to use trajectry optimization using KInematic Trajectory Optimization and I am using [this deepnote](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Manipulation-ac8201a1-470a-4c77-afd0-2cc45bc229ff/project/08-Motion-Planning-0762b167-402a-4362-9702-7d559f0e73bb/%2Fkinematic_trajectory_optimization.ipynb). But the problem is when I add an object to the plant, also the object is considered in the optimization prog. How can I exclude this object from being considered in the optimization.

I am kinda new to the drake and I kinda don't know how to exclude an object from conraints.

Thanks in advance, I am kinda in rush :)
[drake](/questions/tagged/drake)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: I think you want to create a separate MultibodyPlant to your KinematicTrajectoryOptimization that doesn't have the objects in it.

More generally, it's very common to have multiple plants flowing through your robot + control stack, e.g. one for the "robot model" and another for the "robot + objects in the world" model. (It's reasonable that the physics engine's model of the world would be different than the model in the head of the robot). Currently in Drake, it's more recommended to just load two independent plants, rather than try to add/remove objects from an existing plant.